HTTP Request Jmeter response 400 failed IllegalArgumentException
I am trying to do performance testing for soap https request using jmeter and response failed with error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line[: ] doesnot conform to RFC 7230.The request has been rejected
I have added HTTP sampler and HTTP header manager with

soapAction: "document/http://siebel.com/customui:Get_spec"
content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Accept-encoding: gzip,deflate

,but response returned with status code of 400- Bad Request

Please remove colons : from HTTP Header Manager, put only names and values there like this:

More information:

Request header fields
Using JMeter's HTTP Header Manager


I already did that ,but response failed with with error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line[: ] doesnot conform to RFC 7230.The request has been rejected

Try changing header name from soapAction to SOAPAction. You can enable JMeter debug logging for HTTP protocol by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file: <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />, this way you will see what exactly is being sent in jmeter.log file.
